# Python taking too long to exectute simple code... might have entered an infinite loop

Tags: python

I've tried changing variables in case I made a scope error, etc., but nothing seems to work.

I've defined multiple functions for finding frequency of words that appear in a string. It evaluates till two functions but the last function always enters infinite loop... except when there is no repetition.

```
def freq_finder(k):
    dict = {}
    k = k.split(' ')
    for word in k:
        if word in dict:
            dict[word] += 1
        else:
            dict[word] = 1

    return dict


def freq_max(l):
    to_ = freq_finder(l)
    values = to_.values()
    best = max(values)
    words = []
    for t in to_:
        if to_[t] == best:
            words.append(t)

    return (words, best)


def freq_maxi(h):
    values = h.values()
    best = max(values)
    words = []
    for t in h:
        if h == best:
            words.append(t)

    return (words, best)


def words_above_freq(r, freq):
    result = []
    temp_faltu = freq_finder(r)
    done = False
    while not done:
        temp = freq_maxi(temp_faltu)
        if temp[1] >= freq:  # temp[1] is 'best' that was a return from freq_max
            result.append(temp)
            for w in temp[0]:  # temp[0] is the 'words'
                del(temp_faltu[w])

        else:
            done = True

    return result


horde = "I was not was I not"

print(freq_finder(horde))
print(freq_max(horde))
print(words_above_freq(horde, 2))
```

Comment: What are you passing as an argument?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. Adding `print()` statements will help you figure out where the problem is and if you are in an infinite loop.

Comment: @chepner Did you look at all of the code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did not. Missed the scroll bar on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The below function is returning an empty array for words...

```
def freq_max(l):
    to_ = freq_finder(l)
    values = to_.values()
    best = max(values)
    words = []
    for t in to_:
        if to_[t] == best:
            words.append(t)

    return (words, best)
```

This is in turn causing an infinite loop as a condition never gets met for the next function. You actually have many issues in this code and it is way overcomplicated for what you are doing. For example, do not delete elements in an array that is being looped through. This is very nasty.

Finally, look into a module called collections that can do this and more...
https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Or more simply loop through this to find a counter...

```
horde = "I was not was I not"
substring = "I"

count = horde.count(substring)

# print count
print("The count is:", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def freq_finder(k):
...     d = {}
...     k = k.split(' ')
...     for word in k:
...         if word in d:
...             d[word] += 1
...         else:
...             d[word] = 1
...     return d
... 
>>> horde = "I was not was I not"
>>> print(freq_finder(horde))
{'I': 2, 'was': 2, 'not': 2}
```

the problem is that you're overwriting `dict` which is a python class for dictionaries.

Using another name (for example `d`) fix te problem.

```
>>> def freq_max(l):
...     to_ = freq_finder(l)
...     values = to_.values()
...     best = max(values)
...     words = []
...     for t in to_:
...         if to_[t] == best:
...             words.append(t)
...     return (words, best)
... 
>>> print(freq_max(horde))
(['I', 'was', 'not'], 2)
```

this seems ok, I don't think you had an infinite loop, this cannot happen because freq_finder cannot return an infinite dictionary.

Hint:
add `breakpoint()` in the code where you want to understand things and use

`!<variable name>` to print variables

`n` to go ahead by 1 line

`l` to print where you're in the code

`c` to run till the end

`exit` to exit

for example create a file called freq_utils.py and put the code inside:

```
def freq_finder(k):
    breakpoint()
    d = {}
    k = k.split(' ')
    for word in k:
        if word in d:
            d[word] += 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1
    return d

horde = "I was not was I not"
print(freq_finder(horde))


$ python3 /tmp/freq_utils.py 
> /tmp/freq_utils.py(4)freq_finder()
-> d = {}
(Pdb) !d
*** NameError: name 'd' is not defined
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/freq_utils.py(5)freq_finder()
-> k = k.split(' ')
(Pdb) !d
{}
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/freq_utils.py(6)freq_finder()
-> for word in k:
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/freq_utils.py(7)freq_finder()
-> if word in d:
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/freq_utils.py(10)freq_finder()
-> d[word] = 1
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/freq_utils.py(6)freq_finder()
-> for word in k:
(Pdb) !d
{'I': 1}
(Pdb) c
{'I': 2, 'was': 2, 'not': 2}
```